# Using switch statement to convert temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa

Tags: java, switch-statement

This is the question.
Please only use switch statements to do this.
This is my code. When i run it, it gives me error. SS of error http://prntscr.com/1dvvr7
Help me with my code D:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double Degrees_F,f,F;
    double DegreesC,c,C;
    double x;
    int temp;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter temperature ");
    x=keyboard.nextInt( );

    System.out.println("Enter C or c for Celcius or an F/f for Fahrenheit");
    temp=keyboard.nextInt( );

    switch (temp)
     {
    case 'C':

        Degrees_F = 9*(x/5)+32;
        System.out.println(x+"n Fahrenheit is"+Degrees_F);

        break;
    case 'c':
        Degrees_F = 9*(x/5)+32;
        System.out.println(x+"n Fahrenheit is"+Degrees_F);


     }





}
```

}

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: question is what is wrong with my code >.>

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of errors in this piece of work. It doesn't look like the fruit of an honest attempt at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here

`temp=keyboard.nextInt( );`

You can use another readers as `BuffererReader`
or

`char temp = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);`

Another issues in your code :

temp should be char

```
switch(temp){
 case 'C': 
 case 'c':
    Degrees_F = 9*(x/5)+32; // Degrees_F should be degreesF
    System.out.println(x+"n Fahrenheit is"+Degrees_F);
   break;
 default: 
    // show an error message;
}
```

// Another one

```
 System.out.println("Enter temperature ");
    x=keyboard.nextDouble( );
```

Comment: ...and `//code` should appear only once :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik xD i edited

Comment: Thanks using this worked char temp = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a `String/char` value and trying to get a `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're scanning for an int but asking the user to input a character.

Additionally, it looks like you're scanning for Ints but you're storing that value into a double. This would limit the user in terms of what they can input I would think.